# Problems running Mathematica 10 with Workbench 2 Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: version-10, java, workbench

My Workbench runs perfectly using Mathematica 9, however simple things which run just using the Mathematica 10 front end won't run when using Mathematica 10 and Workbench 2.

These simple two lines of code produce errors when workbench is used.
Any insight would be much appreciated

Markus

```
ids = "C:/Mathematica/Data/";
rawdata = Import[ids <> "DATA8.XLS"][[1]]
```

> LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin\javaw"
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\[Ellipsis] wolfram.jlink.JLinkSystemClassLoader com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\m-38eb99ec-4611-4185-9090-ae0d23ac0ad9",183,8]
>   in LinkReadyQ[LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin\javaw"
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Res[Ellipsis] m.jlink.JLinkSystemClassLoader com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\m-38eb99ec-4611-4185-9090-ae0d23ac0ad9",183,8]]
>   has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed. >>
>
> LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin\javaw"
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\[Ellipsis] wolfram.jlink.JLinkSystemClassLoader com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\m-38eb99ec-4611-4185-9090-ae0d23ac0ad9",183,8]
>   in LinkConnectedQ[LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin\javaw"
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Wolfram R[Ellipsis] jlink.JLinkSystemClassLoader com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\m-38eb99ec-4611-4185-9090-ae0d23ac0ad9",183,8]]
>   has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed. >>
>
> LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin\javaw"
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\[Ellipsis] wolfram.jlink.JLinkSystemClassLoader com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\m-38eb99ec-4611-4185-9090-ae0d23ac0ad9",183,8]
>   in LinkReadyQ[LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin\javaw"
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Res[Ellipsis] m.jlink.JLinkSystemClassLoader com.wolfram.jlink.Install -init
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\m-38eb99ec-4611-4185-9090-ae0d23ac0ad9",183,8]]
>   has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed. >>

Comment: I had a similar problem (on Linux though) and I reported it to WRI. They said a new version addressing this issue will be made available soon.

Comment: @b.gatessucks a new version of...what? Workbench or Mathematica?

Comment: @magma Workbench.

Comment: @b.gatessucks well, let's hope so. A new version of WB is long overdue